# AdMob Banner using Objective-c Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6, admob

I'm trying to implement an ad banner into my app, and I'm using the code that google gives you off their site but I'm still getting error as shown bellow. Why am I have these problems? am I missing anything?[image]

I'm now getting this problem when I run the app -

2015-07-17 09:59:16.459 Jus Reign[7155:1055744] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key bannerVIew.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1865e82d8 0x1982bc0e4 0x1865e7f5c 0x187421480 0x186513520 0x18b480734 0x18b37c318 0x18b0609bc 0x18b060928 0x18b067164 0x18b064814 0x18b0d6880 0x18b2eaa28 0x18b2ed19c 0x18b2eb70c 0x18ee1d3c8 0x1865a027c 0x18659f384 0x18659d9a8 0x1864c92d4 0x18b0cc3d0 0x18b0c6f40 0x1000b4de0 0x198966a08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

on the code -

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

}

and it says Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

sorry if I sound really dumb about all this but I'm still a beginner

Comment: Please post your code, instead a screenshot.  This is not readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, XCode thinks that your banner view is a regular *UIView*. To fix it:

- Make sure that you set the custom class of your banner view to *GADBannerView*.
- In your Objective-C code for the view controller, change the declaration of *bannerView* from *UIView* to *GADBannerView*.

Comment: Thank you so much, all my errors have gone but now when I run my app I get 'Thread 1: Breakpoint 2.2' on the code @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GADBannerView *GADBannerView;